# C# Get operators result type

Tags: c#, .net

I have two types stored in strings and I need to get the type resulting the addition/division/... of both of them :

```
"test" + 2 // would give "string"  
2 - 2.2f // would give "float"
```

and so on...
I can already do it if one of them isn't a primitive or a string ( Like System.DateTime ), but I can't find how to do it ( clean )...
The best shot I've got right now is to build these two methods at runtime and call the "GetResultType" method :

```
Type GetTemplateType<T>(T? t) where T: struct => typeof(T);
Type GetResultType() => GetTemplateType(true ? null : ((int?)null) + ((double?)null));
```

the "int" and "double" in the above code would be hard coded in the generated code, so it would essentially rely on the compiler to resolve the type.
I find this method a little ugly so I was wondering if there would be a more clean way to do it?

Edit:

I don't have a value for the variables. I'm building a visual programming interface so I need to know the resulting type of adding two variables without knowing the value of those variables. I would essentially need a method like this :

```
string GetResultingTypeOfAddition( string type1, string type2 ) { ... }
...
var type = GetResultingTypeOfAddition(node1.Type, node2.Type);
```

off course all the `"string"` variables can also be `"System.Type"` variables...
I could've hard coded all the possibilities but I was looking for an existing way to use reflection  ( or whatever ) to get the resulting type!

Comment: hey can you give a better example in code in regards to your `string + int` and `int - float` thanks

Comment: can you show in actual code how are you assigning a value to a variable and it's type `"test" + 2 // would give "string`,show actual code not string + int value..

Comment: If you're the one who decides what the result type should be, you could hard-code it in a dictionary, using the types as `key` and return type as `value`

Comment: Well I'm not deciding of the result type, I just need the real resulting type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option might be to store a set of 'sample data' for each of the relevant types, and then do an actual operation with the combination you are looking for.

As an example (showing just `string` and `float` but extendable to all relevant types):

```
// Setup sample data (keyed by Type, but could be Type's FullName or whatever really)
Dictionary< Type, object> exampleTypes = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
exampleTypes.Add(typeof(string), "a");
exampleTypes.Add(typeof(float), 1.0f);

// Get two bits of sample data
dynamic first = exampleTypes[typeof(string)];
dynamic second = exampleTypes[typeof(float)];

// Apply calculation you are interested in
dynamic bob = first + second;

// OK, float + string results in string
Console.WriteLine(bob.GetType());
```

Comment: I  marked this as accepted, because at least it doesn't require to hard-code all 15 * 15 possibilities, but simply an array of 15 values. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not possible to use reflection (or something else straightforward) to obtain type of "x+y" knowing types of x and y because it's compiler's job to find method that actually will be called in this case (including proper search through all implicit casts and overloaded operators).

Options:

- You can replicate compiler's rules that govern operator selection (hard)
- Compile source code with call the operator with desired arguments at run time and check type of result (`default(Type)` is the way to get sample value
- If you have limited choices for types you may simply hardcode all possibilities and store in dictionary
- reverse problem and limit set of available operators to something you already know results - like cast all numeric types to `double` before calling operator
- see if you can use `dynamic` to obtain type (`(((dynamic)x) + y).GetType()`), you'd need to figure out how to get non-null sample value for reference types like `string`.